# Continuity along all curves imples continuity everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be a function such that $f\circ \gamma$ is continuous for all curves $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$.

Is it necessary that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If $x_n \to x$ in the plane, can you make a planar curve that contains all $x_n$ and ends in $x$?

Comment: Alright, thanks